# seaborn heatmap from pandas dataframe with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, nan, heatmap

Hi I really want to create a heatmap but am struggling:

```
# correlations between undergrad studies and occupation
data_uni = n.groupby(['Q5','Q6'])['Q6'].count().to_frame(name = 'count').reset_index()
# some participants did not answer the question in the survey
data_uni.fillna('Unknown', inplace=True)

data_uni.pivot(index='Q5', columns='Q6', values='count')
plt.figure(1, figsize=(14,10))
sns.heatmap(data_uni, cmap="YlGnBu")
```

The error message I get is **"TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"**.

Is this the right way to create a heatmap? If yes, what am I doing wrong, and if not, what would be the right way? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10):

As per issue [GH375](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/375), you can specify a mask, where data will not be shown for those cells whose mask values are `True`.

```
sns.heatmap(data_uni, cmap="YlGnBu", mask=data_uni.isnull())
```